# Javascript date countdown goes into negative. How do I stop at zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to fix a counter developed for my website so that it either stops at all zeros, or shows a custom message once it reaches zero.  Presently it starts to display negative numbers.  Here is the code provided:

```
 eventTimer: function () {
            eventsDate = $('.eventBox').attr('data-edate');
            today = new Date();
            BigDay = new Date(eventsDate);
            msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
            e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
            daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
            e_hrsLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft) * 24;
            hrsLeft = Math.floor(e_hrsLeft);
            minsLeft = Math.floor((e_hrsLeft - hrsLeft) * 60);
            $('.counter').html("<span>" + daysLeft + "</span> &nbsp;days&nbsp; <span>" + hrsLeft + "</span> &nbsp;hours&nbsp; <span>" + minsLeft + "</span>&nbsp; minutes");
        },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If value <= 0 value = 0

Comment: `clearInterval()` upon `value == 0`, if you're using `setInterval()` to decrement your counter

Comment: If you have a reference to the original interval ID that was returned when `setInterval` was first called you'd be able to cancel it using `clearInterval(intervalId)`.

Comment: @SamKreps : you may check out my answer below

Comment: After the line calculating `timeLeft`, add `if(timeLeft>0)` and block (`{}`) the rest of the code, then add `else $('.counter').html("Big day has arrived!");`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to prevent the `daysLeft`, `minsLeft` and `hrsLeft` values dropping below zero is to wrap them in `Math.abs()`:

```js
eventTimer: function () {
  eventsDate = $('.eventBox').attr('data-edate');
  today = new Date();
  BigDay = new Date(eventsDate);
  msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
  e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
  daysLeft = Math.abs(Math.floor(e_daysLeft));
  e_hrsLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft) * 24;
  hrsLeft = Math.abs(Math.floor(e_hrsLeft));
  minsLeft = Math.abs(Math.floor((e_hrsLeft - hrsLeft) * 60));
  $('.counter').html("<span>" + daysLeft + "</span> &nbsp;days&nbsp; <span>" + hrsLeft + "</span> &nbsp;hours&nbsp; <span>" + minsLeft + "</span>&nbsp; minutes");
},
```

However, perhaps you should also consider stopping the timer when it hits zero on each. Without seeing the rest of the code that's a bit difficult to ascertain.

Comment: Thanks, but the absolute value would just display a positive integer, not zero.  This is all of the code for the counter - it is simply pulling the date and time from the end user, then comparing it to the date and time we input on the backend of our site.

Comment: @SamKrepps : `Math.max(0, value)`

Comment: Correct, my bad, Yevgen's suggestion is the correct way.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov if you could implement that into the code where you mean it would be a big help.  I'm new to this kind of code